# Why does my project crash with an error of Failed to find cgroup for tid 12042

Tags: java, kotlin

So I have my barcode program running based off of Firebase and a tutorial I found on youtube.  I have my phone hooked up to computer and when I run it, I get a crash.

Here is my logcat.

```
2022-02-17 10:53:13.034 12042-12042/? E/USNET: USNET: appName: com.example.barcodescanner
2022-02-17 10:53:13.565 12042-12083/com.example.barcodescanner E/SchedPolicy: Failed to find cgroup for tid 12042
2022-02-17 10:53:13.593 12042-12085/com.example.barcodescanner E/SchedPolicy: Failed to find cgroup for tid 12042
2022-02-17 10:53:13.601 12042-12086/com.example.barcodescanner E/SchedPolicy: Failed to find cgroup for tid 12042
2022-02-17 10:53:13.602 12042-12087/com.example.barcodescanner E/SchedPolicy: Failed to find cgroup for tid 12042
2022-02-17 10:53:13.648 12042-12042/com.example.barcodescanner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.barcodescanner, PID: 12042
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.barcodescanner/com.example.barcodescanner.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: test4: uid 10 does not have android.permission.CAMERA.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5253)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:54)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2425)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8582)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:563)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: test4: uid 10 does not have android.permission.CAMERA.
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:2273)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforcePermission(ContextImpl.java:2282)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforcePermission(ContextWrapper.java:911)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforcePermission(ContextWrapper.java:911)
        at com.example.barcodescanner.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.kt:125)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1476)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8433)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5187)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5253) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:54) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2425) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8582) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:563) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
```

Here is my activity_main.kt

```
package com.example.barcodescanner

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanner
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.common.Barcode
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage
import java.lang.Exception

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   lateinit var btnScanBarcode: Button
   lateinit var ivQrCode:ImageView
   lateinit var tvResult:TextView
   private val CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 123
   private val READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 113
   private val WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 113

   private lateinit var cameraLauncher:ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
   private lateinit var galleryLauncher:ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>

   private val TAG="MyTag"
   lateinit var inputImage: InputImage
   lateinit var barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       btnScanBarcode = findViewById(R.id.btnScanBarcode)
       ivQrCode = findViewById(R.id.ivQrCode)
       tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tvResult)
       barcodeScanner=BarcodeScanning.getClient()

       cameraLauncher=registerForActivityResult(
           ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
       ) { result ->
           val data = result?.data

           try {
               val photo = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
               inputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(photo, 0)
               processQr()
           } catch (e: Exception) {
               Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + e.message)
           }
       }
       galleryLauncher=registerForActivityResult(
           ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
       ) { result ->
           val data = result?.data

           inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(this@MainActivity, data?.data!!)
           processQr()
       }

       btnScanBarcode.setOnClickListener {
           val options= arrayOf("camera", "gallery")
           val builder= AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
           builder.setTitle("Pick An Option")
           builder.setItems(options) { dialog, which ->
               if (which == 0) {
                   val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                   cameraLauncher.launch(cameraIntent)
               } else {
                   val storageIntent = Intent()
                   storageIntent.setType("image/*")
                   storageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                   galleryLauncher.launch(storageIntent)
               }
           }

           builder.show()
       }
   }

   private fun processQr(){
       ivQrCode.visibility= View.GONE
       tvResult.visibility=View.VISIBLE
       barcodeScanner.process(inputImage).addOnSuccessListener {
           for(barcode:Barcode in it){
               when (barcode.valueType) {
                   Barcode.TYPE_WIFI ->{
                       val ssid = barcode.wifi!!.ssid
                       val password = barcode.wifi!!.password
                       val type = barcode.wifi!!.encryptionType

                       tvResult.text="ssid: ${ssid} \n password: ${password} \n ${type}"
               }
                   Barcode.TYPE_URL -> {
                       val title = barcode.url!!.title
                       val url = barcode.url!!.url

                       tvResult.text="Title: ${title} \n URL: ${url}"
               }
                   Barcode.TYPE_TEXT -> {
                       val data = barcode.displayValue

                       tvResult.text="Text: ${data}"

                   }
               }
           }
       }.addOnFailureListener {
           Log.d(TAG, "processQr: ${it.message}")
       }
   }

       override fun onResume(){
           super.onResume()
           enforcePermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE, 10,"test4")
       }

   override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
       requestCode: Int,
       permissions: Array<out String>,
       grantResults: IntArray
   ) {
       super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

       if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
           if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               enforcePermission(
                   android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
               , 10,"Test")
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Camera Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           }
       } else if (requestCode == READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
           if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               enforcePermission(
                   android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
               , 10,"test2")
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Storage Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                   .show()
           }
       } else if (requestCode == WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
           if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               enforcePermission(
                   android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
               , 10,"test3")
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: test4: uid 10 does not have android.permission.CAMERA`

Comment: How do I get the proper uid?

Comment: I don't know Android, so I can't say. Have you given your program the necessary permission to access the camera?